# How do I take a snapshot of the Android emulator's state?

Tags: android, emulation, snapshot

When I launch the Android emulator from the **Android SDK and AVD Manager** I can check the boxes **Launch from snapshot** and **Save to snapshot** so that the emulator's state is saved when I close it and restored again when I launch it. This is great because I don't have to wait for Android to boot each time the emulator is launched. However, I also want to take snapshots of the emulator's state during a session and later during the session revert back to the snapshot, for example to re-run my tests. How do I do this? There do not seem to be any controls for this in the AVD Manager.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842612/how-do-you-save-android-emulator-snapshot/5980578#5980578). To take and load snapshots, start a Telnet session to the emulator:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
avd snapshot save snapshot_name
OK
avd snapshot load snapshot_name
OK
```

The Android emulator freezes for a few seconds while saving/loading a snapshot. You can also list the snapshots using `avd snapshot list`.

Comment: As @Chris pointed out in the comment above, the snapshots are a bit finicky. I have seen spontaneous reboots of the Android OS after loading a snapshot.

Comment: this doesnt work for me. I get "KO: unnown command, try 'help' is it still possible to get a snapshot of the emulator running API 23?

Comment: It seems to be available upto Tools 24 (= API 24), then it throws an error in Tools v25 to the tune of the capability is not supported, but in Tools v26, there is no error, so i suspect it might be available again, but I haven't got it working yet :-(

Comment: ... And Google seems to know about this. See their [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231643&q=%22emulator%20console%22%20%20Subcomponent%3DTools-emulator%20opened-after%3A2016%2F1%2F1&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)