# Android studio run emulator snapshot

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu, android-snapshot

I'm using the latest android studio (2.3.3), and apparently, Google removed the snapshot option when creating a new avd.
I need to create an avd that supports snapshotting like in those threads: 
[how do you save android emulator snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842612/how-do-you-save-android-emulator-snapshot) 
[How do I take a snapshot of the Android emulator's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218066/how-do-i-take-a-snapshot-of-the-android-emulators-state) 
PS.
when I try to run the "avd snapshot save NAME" inside the emulator console interface, nothing happening.
any ideas?

Comment: Can't you save from the AVD Manager?

Comment: If you mean from the manager inside the Android studio then no, they also deprecated the old standalone manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest canary build of AS this is called 'quick boot'. See https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/emulator.html

Comment: Finally! looks great, I will test it