# Android Emulator booting time

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, terminal

I am using Android virtual device for 2.1 Eclair . Emulator takes nearly about 2 mins in booting process,how can we reduce to booting time?

Answer (score 2):

While you create an emulator from AVD Manager you can tick on the checkbox **Enable Snapshot**. start emulator first time from AVD Manager and again tick SnapShot. After emulator started close it and run your application in that emulator.

The initial booting time will not be reduced. But the further running time will be reduced a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is very usual. When working with your development open the emulator and fetch a cup of coffee while its booting. Then dont shut it down before you stop working again. You can keep running and debugging the same project into the same emulator the whole day if you would like.

Best regards
Jonas

Answer (score 1):

Throught the terminal issue a command: <kbd>emulator -avd "device name" -no-boot-anim</kbd> through this emulator will bootup without animition,for more info http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can.
You can save snapshot of the emulator and then resume the same session next time.
Here is topic about it: [how do you save android emulator snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842612/how-do-you-save-android-emulator-snapshot)

Answer (score 0):

Even though snapshot help you to decrease time, it is buggy (at least for me). So boot your emulator time to time