# Can't find stop button in Android Studio to stop the emulator

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I don't know how to stop the emulator. Apparently, there's supposed to be a stop button but it's not there?

Answer (score 56):

You can close the running Emulator by clicking the `x` button at the top of the Emulator tab (see image below)

[image]

Comment: I confirm that this works in my case. I am using version Bumblebee.

Comment: the fact we had to Google this reminds me why .... nevermind... this should be the accepted answer

Comment: It is a little counterintuitive, because the tooltip says only *Close tab (Ctrl+Shift+F4).* But I may confirm that it really works.

Comment: Ah thanks!! I've been looking for 30 minutes now without finding that x

Comment: Note: this doesn't actually "kill" the emulator and force a cold boot the next time. It just snapshots it. So, if you're trying to actually restart the emulator due to some issue, you need to go into the AVD Manager and "Cold boot now" on the emulator of choice

Comment: This does not work, it only hides the tab/window. If you check the task manager, the qemu process is still running, and if you click play, the emulator window/tab shows up instantly, indicating that indedd the emulator was still running, the only way to shut it down was to close android studio.

Comment: @dioslibre Not true. It takes a moment but the processes are finished then.

Answer (score 12):

1. Print a list of your devices:

   adb devices
2. Kill it using emu

   adb -s emulator-5432 emu kill

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can close the Emulator by clicking the **X** button at the top of emulator window. I found this answer on another stack overflow thread. There they've provided a complete explanation along with the original documentation. If you want you can check out that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079212/android-emulator-wont-shut-down?msclkid=1f75fd7ccf2e11ec8e1d5ef78ca65aa9)

Answer (score 2):

I know of no other way than the command line, as @Tian said. Closing the emulator window has no effect as far as I know.

1. Open a terminal window (either the AS one or any other, as long as adb commands are available)
2. List the running connected devices with: `adb devices`
3. Identify your emulator in the resulting list (usually in the form of: `emulator-5556 device`)
4. Now kill the emulator with: `adb -s emulator-5556 emu kill` (replace the name of your own emulator in the command of course)
5. You'll see a confirmation message like `OK: killing emulator, bye bye`

Comment: Closing/hiding the Emulator window might not have an effect but clicking the X to close the tab for that emulator has the exact same effect as the kill command. You can verify this with `adb devices` and in the memory usage of your machine.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS delete files corresponding to

```
/Users/Your-User/.android/avd/Your-Device-name.avd/*.lock
```

In my case there were 2 files:

- /Users/user/.android/avd/Pixel_5_API_33.avd/hardware-qemu.ini.lock
- /Users/user/.android/avd/Pixel_5_API_33.avd/multiinstance.lock

Answer (score 0):

no stop button in bumblebee I also failed to find a way to stop it pressing the power button for long shows options lockdown poweroff and restart which in my case didnt work checked avd location lock file was created so finally killed it through taskmanager by ending qemu task