# Android Studio not shutting down properly - emulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When I close Android Studio, after closing the Emulator by clicking the `x` button in the navigation menu, the emulators stay open in the Task Manager.

Three processes remain open:
The **emulator**, the **emulator crash service**, and something called **qemu**.

When I boot up Android Studio the next time, I cannot open a new emulator as long as these three are open, I get a `has terminated` error. I have to end all three tasks to make it work.

So does anyone know how to close Android Studio properly, where it also terminates any emulator processes as well?

Comment: Visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079212/android-emulator-wont-shut-down

Comment: @AliNajafZadeh It's outdated.