# Cannot save snapshot AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, amd-processor

Each time, starting the emulator, everything happens as if for the first time, and I can not save a snapshot and getting error 'Could not save snapshot' and 'Skipping snapshot save: current state doesn...'. However 'Quick boot' and Hardware Graphics options are enabled, looks like my pc cant even save it for some reasons. Everything is updated, help with solving the problem.
I have AMD Ryzen 5 2600 if it matters.
My screenshots:
[AVD screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffekm.png)
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDQeO.png)

Comment: I had same issue and this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/52666525/811922